# R use column name string as a function parameter to reference column

Tags: r

I've been trying to calculate the mean of a column in a data.frame inside a function which I pass teh data.frame and the name of the column to calculate but I'm not able to do so

This is an example of the data

```
aleatorio<-rnorm(1:52)
cod_prov<-c(1:52)
datosprov<-cbind(cod_prov, aleatorio)
rm(aleatorio,cod_prov)
```

This is the function

```
prueba<-function(bbdd,varmap){
  forMap<-noquote(paste0(substitute(bbdd),"$",substitute(varmap)))
  mean(forMap)
}

 
prueba(datosprov,"positivo")
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for `data.frames`. As @jay.sf points correctly out in the comments, @Otto Kässis approach is safer since it works on data.frames and matrices. The approach below is useful if you want to use bare names instead of strings to select variables *in a data.frame*.

```r
prueba <- function(bbdd,varmap){
  mean(bbdd[[substitute(varmap)]])
}

prueba(iris, Sepal.Length)
#> [1] 5.843333
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can access columns within a dataframe by `df[,'colname']`, i.e.

```
 prueba<-function(bbdd,varmap){
   forMap<-bbdd[,varmap]
   mean(forMap)
 }

>  prueba(datosprov,"aleatorio")
[1] -0.1167871
```